# Value of Binding not showing up in ios but works normally on android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

When displaying a page with two data binding the values show up perfectly in android as shown here:

[image: Android simulator screenshot]

But when running on ios only one of the values show up:

[image: iOS simulator screenshot (iOS version 14.1)]

The xaml code for the page looks like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MultiTest.PaymentPage"
             Title="Confirm Payment">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin ="20" Spacing="5">
            <Label Text="Top Up Value: "
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               />
            <Label Text="{Binding Denominations}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                
                   x:Name="TopUpValue"/>
            <Label Text="Meter Number:"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                />
            <Label Text="{Binding MeterNumber}"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
              
                   x:Name="CreditCardDetails"/>
            <Button Text="To Payment" Clicked="ToConfirmPayment"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Is there some extra confing I'm missing in the ios version?

EDIT: Here's some of the code behind for the app:

Payment.cs (the class used to store the data needed):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MultiTest.Models
{
    public class Payment
    {
        public string Denominations { get; set; }
        public string MeterNumber { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return MeterNumber;
        }



    }
}
```

ConfirmTopUp.xaml.cs(the code behind for the view):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MultiTest.Models;
using MultiTest.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MultiTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PaymentPage : ContentPage
    {

       //public Payment topUp;
        public PaymentPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new Payment();
        }

        async void ToConfirmPayment(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PaymentConfirmation());
        }
    }
}
```

TopUpOptions.xaml.cs(the view where the data is passed from):

```
  var paymentDetails = new Payment
                        {
                            Denominations = topUpValue.ToString(),
                            MeterNumber = meter.MeterNumber
                        };

                        var toPayment = new PaymentPage();
                        toPayment.BindingContext = paymentDetails;
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(toPayment);
```

Comment: Can you please share us the codes in code behind?

Comment: Added some code, hopefully this can help make it a bit clearer. Just to add: the iOS simulator in the screenshot was running iOS 14.1

Comment: Would the issue happen if you change the Denominations = topUpValue.ToString() to Denominations = "test"?

Comment: Yes the issue still occurs just tested after cleaning and building the solution

Comment: It works well on my side. Does it work if you directly give a string in xaml without using binding?

Comment: It seems to display correctly if I add  System.Console.WriteLine("Denominations:");
                        System.Console.WriteLine(paymentDetails.Denominations); to TopUpOptions.xaml.cs

Comment: It looks like the paymentDetails.Denominations does not set the value if you does not call it. If you can share more codes to reproduce the issue, I will check.